# How to use URL:: or asset() in config files in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

In any config file If I use URL class I get the error 'Class URL not found'; if I use the function "asset", when I update composer.json I get this error:
Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given,

Outside of config files both work fine

```
return [
    'photos_url' => URL::asset('xxx'),
];
```

or

```
return [
    'photos_url' => asset('xxx'),
];
```

Test

```
echo config('site.photos_url'); // or echo Config::get('site.photos_url');
```

Comment: Because the URL generator isn't ready yet. Cant you just store the `xxx` part in the config and generate the full URL when you need it? If you want to have the nice syntax you could create a little helper function that applies `asset()` for you...

Answer (score 6):

Configs are loaded really early and probably not meant to use anything from the framework except **Dotenv**

```
return [
    'photos_url' => URL::asset('xxx'),
];
```

Instead you can use:

```
return [
    'photos_url' => env('APP_URL').'/rest_of_path.ext',
];
```

Source: Laravel Issue [#7671](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7671)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use dynamic code in your config. As a solution you can use `ConfigServiceProvider` to add any specific cases:

```
public function register()
{
    config([
        'photos_url' => assets('xxx'),
        'services.facebook.redirect' => url('auth/callback/facebook'),
    ]);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7671